# How can I count how many records have a field populated?

Tags: apex, trigger

<del>Aim/ count how many times the field "first name"is populate on the account object</del>

Aim: count the number of Account records which have the First Name field populated.

Anyone got any ideas how I can do this ?

Looking forward to your response

Daniel

Comment: First name? As in, person accounts or contacts on each account? And do you mean when it changes?

Comment: Hi sfdcfox. - I want to count how many times the "first name" on the account object is not blank. To be fair it can a field like website, just want to understand the logic to use.

Comment: @Masond3 are you trying to get a total count of the number of Account records which have the First Name field populated?

Comment: @ mark pond - yes , you hit it on the head

Comment: There's a handy and free tool on the app exchange called Field Trip which does what you're looking for: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4 (Disclaimer, this is not my app or company)

Comment: Kbentsen - the app doesn't serve the required purpose. I am however trying to achieve samelogic though

Comment: Depending on how many Account records are in the org, you could achieve this with a simple query with FirstName != NULL clause. Edit: I am assuming you have at least a basic familiarity with Apex.

Comment: @kbentasn- I have over 50 fields so I don't want to manual hard code every field. Anyway you. An do a select * = null clause ? And would that give me a one liner per field eg first name 5,

Answer (score 2):

Use the [count(fieldname) SOQL function](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_count.htm) to count records for which the field is not null:

```
select count(firstname) from Account
```

This also lets you filter further.  For example, if you only want to count how many Calfornia accounts have firstname populated:

```
select count(firstname) from Account where BillingState = 'California'
```

Comment: Anyway I can make it dynamic so instead of hard coding the field name/api names it knows when a new field is added

Comment: You can use Dynamic SOQL (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) to construct your query string at run time, allowing you to check any field if you know the fieldname; you can use SObject describe information (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm) to enumerate fields on an object.  However, this is a technique for counting the number of records where a single field is populated.  If you have further requirements, you should refine your question.